# Can we use functions like concat() group_concat() in show statement?

Tags: mysql, show, concatenation, group-concat

For instance I run command

mysql> show tables;

Tables in DB

a

b

c

d

I want to use it such as concat('drop table ', tablename, ';');

So that my result set would become

drop table a;

drop table b;

drop table c;

and so on....

Comment: Use [21.24 The INFORMATION_SCHEMA TABLES Table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tables-table.html).

Comment: Thank you. it's an answer in a comment

mysql> select concat('drop table ',table_name, ';') from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'DB'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [21.24 The INFORMATION_SCHEMA TABLES Table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tables-table.html).

Try:

```sql
SELECT
  CONCAT('drop table ', `TABLE_NAME`, ';')
FROM
  `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`TABLES`
WHERE
  `TABLE_SCHEMA` = DATABASE() AND
  `TABLE_TYPE` = 'BASE TABLE';
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e14e4/1)

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add, if you want to generate a list of databases instead, use something like:

```
SELECT CONCAT('DROP DATABASE `', `table_schema`, '`;') FROM (
    SELECT `table_schema`
    FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.tables
    WHERE `table_schema` != "INFORMATION_SCHEMA" && `table_schema` != "performance_schema"
    GROUP BY `table_schema`
) as dbs
```

Additionally, if you want to have all drop database queries in one row, use [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ts SEPARATOR ' ') as drop_databases_query FROM (SELECT CONCAT('DROP DATABASE `', `table_schema`, '`;') as ts FROM (
    SELECT `table_schema`
    FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.tables
    WHERE `table_schema` != "INFORMATION_SCHEMA" && `table_schema` != "performance_schema"
    GROUP BY `table_schema`
) as dbs) as concatted
```

It will result in something like

```
DROP DATABASE `mydb`; DROP DATABASE `mydb2`; DROP DATABASE `mysql`; DROP DATABASE `sys`;
```